# Is Alien aggression global or is it on a per-nest basis?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

According to [another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/189336/3128) about alien aggression, alien aggression can be lowered by:

> they also become less hostile if an alien nest actually exists within
>   the borders of your city, eventually becoming friendly.

But that leaves me wondering if the aliens become friendly for that nest or city, or do the aliens become friendly globally.

Is alien aggression tracked globally in Beyond Earth?

Comment: It does keep track of a global alien opinion, but I don't know if that's used for hostility or just for determining which alien units spawn. Oddly, the Transcendence victory quest sets `Aliens.SetOpinionForPlayer(quest:GetOwner(), AIAlienOpinionTypes.ALIEN_OPINION_VERY_HOSTILE);`, which seems odd, so the global opinion might just influence spawning after all.

Comment: This seems to be an offshoot of the same question.  I don't believe it needs a separate question.

Comment: @Frank - That question does not answer a fundamental question about how alien aggression works, ie is it global or per nest.  I think this question is easily valid in its own right.  Besides what do you have against more detailed versus more general questions?

Comment: For something that's such a tiny part of the other question, I would recommend adding a comment.

Comment: @Frank - I think you misjudged the question, and you did the people who are interested in the game a disservice.

Comment: I'm actually one of those who play Beyond Earth.  I'm curious how trying to keep questions asking the same thing is doing players a disservice.  The linked question encompasses this one rather handily, and while it's unfortunate that single aspect wasn't answered, the fact is that this has already been asked.

Comment: @frank - I think your wrong, the questions aren't wikipedia pages that will be updated to answer every sub-question.  If people can not ask questions inspired by other questions, then you are needlessly standing in the way of learning and are truly committing a disservice to those who wish to learn.  There really isn't any benefit to erring this strongly on the side of succinctness.

Comment: So attempting to keep related information in the same place is doing players a disservice?  I'm sorry, but I don't agree with you at all.  That's the whole point of duplication; keep questions that ask the same question linked to a single source.  If anything, that's doing players a service, to keep that information all in one area.

Comment: Hey I think you were too aggressive and you throwing the baby out with the bath-water, so to speak.  I'm sorry that you feel the way you do, but obviously you've decided to stick to your guns.

Comment: Relevant Meta: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/is-a-question-a-duplicate-just-because-it-asks-for-something-that-can-be-part-of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alien aggression is tracked locally in Beyond Earth, so the aliens would become friendly only for that nest.

It has been proposed that alien aggression be global [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Fcivbeyondearth%2Fcomments%2F2kfzic%2Foverhaul_for_alien_relations_beyond_barbarian%2F&ei=qHNWVNu7KcPzoASggYHwDA&usg=AFQjCNF9Q0HaHsXCAY06G3YjQ0MH_48nhw&bvm=bv.78677474,d.cGU), but has not yet been implemented.

[Source 1 (A great read, recommended for any civ-beyond-earth player)](http://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/2krt7e/be_anyone_grasped_how_alien_aggression_works/)

Comment: downvoter, explain?